# A topology for the reals which is not a metric topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If we have the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, the family

$$
\mathbb{T}=\lbrace (a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R} \rbrace \cup\lbrace \emptyset,\mathbb{R}\rbrace
$$

is a topology for $\mathbb{R}$. It is claimed that any metric in $\mathbb{R}$ cannot "generate" the topology $\mathbb{T}$.

Question: why not?

Where I am: a metric is always a function on the nonnegative numbers for *any* $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. I can think of negative numbers and evidently intervals such as $(-x,-y)$ (with the metric $|x-y|$) are not in $\mathbb{T}$. However, I can think of another *candidate* for a metric, say $\exp(-|x-y|)$. I haven't proved that this function qualified for a metric, but my point is to have an strange metric such that, e.g. for negative numbers very close to zero,
this metric is unbounded.

In that case, I can think that the metric can "generate" an open set such that it is equal to $\mathbb{R}$. But then $\mathbb{R}\in \mathbb{T}$ which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Have you checked which separation properties $\mathbb{T}$ satisfies? (i.e. is it Hausdorff?)

Comment: For a topological space to be metrizable it must be Hausdorff, among other things. This space isn't Hausdorff so it can't be metrizable.

Comment: @Tyrone no Hausdorff still at this time. It is just a bone thrown by the author of the text in a very first introduction to topology

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $d$ be a metric on $\Bbb R$ and let $r=d(0,1)$. Then the open balls $B_{r/2}(0)$ and $B_{r/2}(1)$ are non-empty open subsets of $\Bbb R$ with empty intersection. But given any two non-empty elements of $\Bbb T$, their intersection is non-empty too.

Comment: Re: the first two sentences, what this really shows is that **every metrizable topology is Hausdorff**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I finally reached Hausdorff after 4 pages. The observation is indeed correct and the proof by José is exactly the proof in the book to show that every metrizable topology is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on several different comments:<sup>[1]</sup>

The argument given José Carlos Santos is excellent for dealing with this particular example.  Let $d$ be any metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $r = d(0,1)$.  Then
$$ B(0,r/2) \cap B(1,r/2) = \varnothing, $$
where $B(x,\rho)$ is the open ball of radius $\rho$ centered at $x$, i.e. the set
$$ B(x,\rho) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : d(x,y) < \rho\}.$$
On the other hand, both of balls are nonempty, and if $\mathbb{T}$ is generated by the metric $d$,  then both balls must be open.  Hence we have found two nonempty open sets in $\mathbb{T}$ which have empty intersection.  This is a contradiction, since $(a,\infty) \cap (b,\infty)$ is nonempty for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$.

However, this argument can be generalized to a much larger class of examples as follows:  suppose that $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space with underlying set $X$ and topology $\tau$.  Further suppose that there are two points $x$ and $y$ such that if $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$, then $y\in U$ (that is, every open set which contains $x$ also contains $y$).  Then, by a similar argument to the one presented above, there is no metric which generates $\tau$ (that is, $\tau$ is not *metrizable*).  This very naturally leads to the following definition:

> **Definition:**  Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.  The space $X$ is said to be *Hausdorff* (or *$T_2$*) if for any $x,y\in X$, there exist $U,V\in \tau$ such that
>
> - $x \in U$,
> - $y \in V$, and
> - $U \cap V = \varnothing$.
>
> That is, any two points can be *separated* by open sets.

What the argument above shows is that every metrizable space *must* be Hausdorff, as we can always separate points by balls with radius have the distance between those two points.  Note that, while being Hausdorff is necessary for metrizability, it is not sufficient, i.e. there exist examples of Hausdorff spaces which are not metrizable.

---

[1] Credit to [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos), [Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber), [Tyrone](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/258571/tyrone) and [CyclotomicField](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464974/cyclotomicfield) for bringing up the Hausdorff property in various comments.